# How use Spring Cloud Server without GitHub

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I noticed I am obligated to inform the GitHub address to use Spring Cloud Server, but if don't have one for my projects.

Could I use for example a CVS repository to get those sources? Or may just use a simple local code as Eureka server offers?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can work with a local git repository by using an `file:` url.

Comment: At the moment all our servers are based on CVS. Is there any way to execute without repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using spring.profiles.active: native you can read the configuration from local files.

Look at the "File System Backend" section in http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html